# limiting the occurence of one character across a whole regex string

Tags: java, regex

I want an alphanumeric (not a word) string between 3 and 50 characters long.  It can have no more that 3 whitespaces in it.  The best I've come up with is:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,50}[\s]{0,3}$` 
but this doesn't work.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The easiest is to add a negative lookahead at the beginning, add a whitespace to the character class and remove `[\s]{0,3}`: `^(?!(?:.*\s){4})[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{3,50}$`. Incidentally, `[\s]` is the same as `\s`.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `(?!(?:\S*\s){4})` in the lookahead part, it cause less effort.

Comment: @Cary Sorry if I stole your solution :D but when I started writing my answer, your comment only mentioned the Lookahead and didn't include the full pattern.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, not a problem. I had no plans to submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) has suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121043/limiting-the-occurence-of-one-character-across-a-whole-regex-string#comment127431136_72121043), you may use a negative Lookahead to ensure that the string doesn't have more than 3 whitespace characters. The full pattern would be something like this:

```
^(?!(?:.*\h){4})[A-Za-z0-9\h]{3,50}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6dxjeu/1)**.

Note that I used `\h` instead of `\s` here in order to only match horizontal whitespace characters.

If you need to prevent whitespace characters from appearing at the beginning/end of the string, you could adjust the Lookahead and add a negative Lookbehind at the end:

```
^(?!\h|(?:.*\h){4})[A-Za-z0-9\h]{3,50}(?<!\h)$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2tN8F/1)**.